# Коллекция без дублирования элементов

Tags: java, коллекции

Допустим, есть строки `А`, `Б`, `В`, `Я`, `В`. После добавления в какую коллекцию в ней будет только `А`, `Б`, `В`, `Я`? Или велосипед писать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) и [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) относятся к семейству [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). В множествах `Set` каждый элемент хранится только в одном экземпляре, а разные реализации `Set` используют разный порядок хранения элементов.

Comment: А если, допустим, нужно `HashMap`перевести в `Set` без дублей по ключам?

Comment: Может вы иммели введу дублей по значению? Ведь Map как таковой не может содержать 2 идентичных ключа

Comment: да, точно, по значению

Comment: Просто прогани значения **HashMap** по ключам и добавь их в **Set**. Если добовлять значение которое уже есть оно будет пропущено.

Comment: С Java 8 можно так? `hashmap.stream().toSet(hashmap::value())`

Comment: new HashSet<>(map.values())

Comment: @Flippy стрим тут ни к чему.